# What's the design principle of syscall?

Tags: system-calls

How does Linux determine that some functionality should be classified as syscall while others can be directly implemented in user space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system call is performed when processing must occur in the Kernel - meaning that it requires escalated privileges or access to kernel-private resources.  Typically if something can be kept in userspace, it's done there.  There could be performance reasons when things are moved to kernel processing, and therefore would require a system call to perform.  Another facet is that the transition between userspace and kernelspace is relatively expensive.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.I know well about how syscall executes.My question is why some functionality deserves being classified as syscall.

Comment: @new_perl maybe to be more clear, if something executes in this manner it's classified for syscall.  If something is classified as syscall there is a requirement for it.  Either A) it's an absolute requirement such as needing access to memory or some other kernel-managed resource, or B) it's a performance based requirement.  I assume you are questioning about B.  For these, it would just be a case by case basis.  I think in general the last resort is to include in the kernel, only in a real need. An example is pthreads/futex functionality where a syscall is created for needed performance gain

Comment: @new_perl Maybe an addendum to the answer is - who ultimately decides?  Well, if you're talking about the vanilla Linux kernel, then it's up to Linus etc who lock it down.  Of course if you're writing a kernel patch or your own driver (think: VMware) you can make the decision as you wish

Comment: I do understand the `in a real need` case,but the kernel guys must have figured out some mechanisms so that kernel managed resources will never be corrupted in userspace,do they store all kernel resources in the higher 2G memory space, but still they sometimes need to store in the filesystem, how do they protect the kernel files?

Comment: @new_perl all kernel memory is protected because of the way memory access works in virtual memory implementations.  When you obtain pointers in to memory, you're actually pointing in to the virtual memory space, which then maps to pages (or segments) in actual memory or in swap on disk.  All requests for memory read or write go through the kernel, which keeps a table of what virtual pages are in use or free, and who owns them.  It's impossible to access kernel memory pages due to this mechanism.  There's simply no mechanism to point to a specific word of RAM from userland.